# Periodically updating textarea value using MVC 4 and Razor

Tags: razor, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the simplest way to update textarea value without refreshing the whole page? Asynchronous method in controller will change textarea value, but how can I update the view? I've read about pushing updates using SignalR, would that kind of approach be helpful?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to update the view"?

Comment: By "updating the view" I meant changing view element properties according to change in back-end done by controller.

Comment: You can send back more data instead of just textarea contents and update the DOM elements based on those data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AjaxOptions specify a javascript method to call OnSuccess

```
        new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "UpdatePage(data)" })
```

Send back a JsonResult from your Action in the Controller

```
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                variable1 = value1,
                variable2 = value2,
                variable3 = value3
            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
```

And in the javascript method process the data you sent back

```
   function UpdatePage(data) {            
        $("input[name='UpdateMe1']").val(data.variable1);
        $("input[name='UpdateMe2']").val(data.variable2);
        $("#UpdateMe3").html(data.variable3);
    }
```